# Unlist column to create unique row in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am faced with the following R transformation issue. 
I have the following dataframe:

```
 test_df <-  structure(list(word = c("list of XYZ schools", 
"list of basketball", "list of usa"), results = c("58", "151", "29"), key_list = structure(list(`coRq,coG,coQ,co7E,coV98` = c("coRq", "coG", "coQ", "co7E", "coV98"), `coV98,coUD,coHF,cobK,con7` = c("coV98","coUD", "coHF", "cobK", "con7"), `coV98,coX7,couC,coD3,copW` = c("coV98", "coX7", "couC", "coD3", "copW")), .Names = c("coRq,coG,coQ,co7E,coV98", "coV98,coUD,coHF,cobK,con7", "coV98,coX7,couC,coD3,copW"))), .Names = c("word", "results", "key_list"), row.names = c(116L, 150L, 277L), class = "data.frame")
```

In short there are three columns, unique on "word" and then a corresponding "key_list" that has a list of keys comma separated. I am interested in creating a new data frame where each key is unique and the word information is duplicated as well as the result information. 
So a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
key          word                    results                    
coV98       "list of XYZ schools"    58
coRq        "list of XYZ schools"    58
coV98       "list of basketball"     151
coV98       "list of usa"            29
```

And so on for all the keys, so I would like to expand the keys unlist them and then reshape into a dataframe with repeating words and other columns.

I have tried a bunch of the following:
Created a unique list of keys and then attempted to grep for each of those keys in the column and loop through to create a new smaller dataframe and then rbind those together, the resulting dataframe however does not contain the key column:

```
keys <- as.data.frame(table(unname(unlist(test_df$key_list))))
ttt <- lapply(keys, function(xx){
      idx <- grep(xx, test_df$key_list)
      df <- all_data_sub[idx,]})
      final_df <- do.call(rbind, ttt)
```

I have also played around with unlisting and reshaping, but I am not getting the right combination. 
Any advice would be great! 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be we can use `listCol_l` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_l(test_df, 'key_list')[]
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, I cannot thank you enough. I was completely unaware of that library, but reading about it, it seems to have alot of helpful manipulations. thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

In case a base R solution is helpful for someone:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(test_df$key_list), function(i) {
    merge(test_df$key_list[[i]], test_df[i,-3], by=NULL)
  }))
```